# <script src=""> не загружает скрипт

Tags: javascript, html

Я может конечно и очень глупенькая, но все никак не могу понять, почего скрипт не подгружается:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  <--- сначала jquery
    <script src="/js/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    <---------- Это он!!
<!--    <script src="/js/authentication.js"></script>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sign-in/">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="bg-light">

<div class="container">
    <main>
        <div class="py-5 text-center">
            <h2>Checkout form</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="container-sm">
                <h4 class="mb-3">Personal info</h4>
                <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="" id="registration">
                    <div class="row g-3">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="registerUsername" class="form-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="input-group has-validation">
                                <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerUsername" placeholder="Username" required="">
                            </div>
                            <small class="text-danger" id="badCredentials"></small>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="registerPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="input-group has-validation">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" id="registerPassword" placeholder="Password" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label for="repeatPassword" class="form-label">Repeat password</label>
                                <div class="input-group has-validation">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" id="repeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat password" required="">
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-danger" id="equalPasswords"></small>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="my-4">
                            <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="text-muted text-center text-small">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Структура каталогов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тоесть я из register формы пытаюсь получить доступ к vаlidate скрипту

(P.S. `../js/validate.js` такая попытка тоже была)

Что я делаю не так?

Запускаю странички из папки в браузере либо из идеи:

1. Захожу в папочку, открываю что мне надо
2. Жму правая кнопка мыши -> открыть с помощью -> Microsoft edge

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ни один, ни другой вариант, к сожалению, не работают

Comment: На чём сервер? У него структура URL-адресов может отличаться от папок на диске. Можете попробовать в браузер вбивать разные варианты, например 'ваш_домен/resources/js/validate.js'

Comment: сервер  в другом модуле) это просто файлы на диске которые лежат в соседних папках - они вовсе не с сервера (просто из идеи удобно писать разметку)

Comment: То есть вы эти html-ки на компьютере запускаете из папки? Или всё же сервер работает какой-то?

Comment: запускаю из папки в браузере на рандомном порту (какой пк выберет), сервер работает, но он rest, и я к нему просто обращаюсь с помощью ajax (это те скрипты которые я не достаю). Сервер есть, но папка со страницами и сам сервер далеко в разных местах

Comment: Вам тогда нужно узнать конфигурацию адресов (роутинг) этого сервера. Возможно он считает всю папку resources например плоской (без вложенности), или отдаёт ресурсы совсем по других адресам, например по 'домен/res/script/bundle.js'

Comment: "я к нему просто обращаюсь с помощью ajax" - ??

Comment: это моя папка, не сервера)

Comment: на веб-странице никогда ничего не работает из папки, всегда по URL, и вы говорите что на порту запускаете. У папок нет портов. И адрес тогда начинался бы с `file:///`.

Comment: с помощью ajax это типа `$.ajax({
            url: serverAddress + loginAddress,
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(userDto),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            statusCode: {
                401: function () {
                    $("#invalidUsername").text('Invalid username or password');
                },
                200: function(res) {
                    alert("Nice!");
                    localStorage.setItem('jwt_token', res.jwtToken);
                }
            }
        });`

Comment: я добавила скрин выше